# Inquirer prompt

Tags: node.js, inquirerjs

When running the demo script from Node.js's [`inquirer` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) the prompt on my terminal appears twice while I would like it to appear only once.

Here is my script:

```
import inquirer from "inquirer"

inquirer
  .prompt([{
        "name":"King of France",
        "message":"Who is the king of France"
    }
  ])
  .then((answers) => {
    // console.log(answers)
    console.log("Nothing should be printed.")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.isTtyError) {
        console.log(erorr)
    } else {
        console.log(error)
    }
  });
```

Which has the following outputs:
[image: console output showing twice the question asked through inquirer.js]

To be more precise, it appears once when I launch the script and a second time just as I reply on my terminal.

Comment: Please provide more information.. details and clarify the issue.

Comment: Picture from console added ! hope it clarifies the question :)

Comment: I think you must ensure that the prompt is displayed only once by wrapping the prompt logic in a function and calling it when needed... like `const askQuestion = () => {// all codes goes here }; askQuestion()`

Comment: I have tried but it still displays the prompt twice. However, thank you very much for the proposition.